# How to enforce integrity for orders?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, e-commerce

If a user can have multiple addresses and phone numbers, is it possible to design the database in such a way that I can enforce integrity between data?

For example:

```
users(id,name)
addresses(id, description, user_id -FK to users)
phones(id, description, user_id -FK to users)
orders(id,address_id -FK addresses,phone_id - FK to phones)
```

How can I be sure that in the orders table I won't accidentally insert a record with `user1` address and `user2` phone number?

I'm sorry if this was asked before but I don't know how to search for this situation.

Comment: Don't store address and phone_id in orders ? Just store users.id

Comment: And how do I know which of the addresses is the order supposed to be shipped at?

Comment: That's what joins are for..Though to be honest unless a user has many addresses and many phones I cannot see why you would have separate tables.

Comment: It is just an example. Imagine the user does have many addresses and phone numbers. For each order he selects one address and one phone number. How do I register the order data so that I record what the user chose?

Comment: Address and phone are attributes of the user, not of the order. So these columns must be removed from orders table. *Imagine the user does have many addresses and phone numbers.* If so then the junction table (user - address) must exist, and order must refer to this table. The same for junction user-phone. PS. It is possible that two or more users shares the same address (for example, spouses). The same about phone.

Comment: Usually, user information like address and phone number is copied into an order table because people move and in most places, there are legal requirements to be able to reproduce an order for years.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `Orders` table?  It will have columns `user_id`, `address_id`, and `phone_id`.

For data entry, if a known user calls in an order, then the UI brings up the *existing* addresses and phones for that user.  The order-taker can quickly click on them.  Or the user can say to use a different address.  Then the UI assists in adding a new address for that user.